# Taphold returning dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

For the life of me I can't figure out a way of doing this. I'm having content returned from a database through a loop. When the div is held down I detect it with the taphold and display a popup box prompting the user. What I need to do is detect which div has been held so I can return the postID to process. Hopefully this example will clear it up.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBox">
    I need to be able to process the post ID of the held div here
</div>

<?php
    while($row = $getContent->fetch()) {
        echo "<div class='popup'>";
            echo $row['postID'];
            .....
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>

<script>
    $(function(){
      $( "div.popup" ).on( "taphold", tapholdHandler );

      function tapholdHandler( event ){
        $("#popupBox").popup('open');
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mvrUE/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("div.popup").on("taphold", function(event) {
        var postId = $(this).text();
        //var postId = parseInt($(this).text());
        $("#popupBox").popup('open');
        var link = $('#popupBox').find('a');
        var url = link.attr('href');
        var newLink = url + '?id=' + postId;
        link.attr('href', newLink);
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply, this works but I do have a couple of problems with it. 1). It does get the variable into the popup box but I need to access that as a PHP variable in the popup opposed to having it printed out although I'm not sure this is possible due to client-server side differences 2). each time I taphold a different div the postID is appended each time so piled up e.g 213 etc...

Comment: What do you need the PHP to do with the ID?

Comment: Actually thinking about it I don't need to put it into a php variable but I do need to put it in a specific place within a string inside that popupBox div. I have a link in there which I need to get the post ID into as opposed to appending it on the end

Comment: I updated my answer. It will find any `a` tag in the popup and change the href to include the `postId`

Comment: Unfortunately using the parseInt method, I have several numbers throughout the div so instead of picking up the specific postId it just picks them all up. Also when appending to the url it adds a # before the ? causing the link not to work, I think that's due to the jquery popup as when that opens it adds a # to the url.

Comment: bottom line, you shouldn't be doing it that way anyway. At least put the postId in a div as a data attribute so you can get via `$(this).find('.someclass').data('postId');`

Comment: I'm open to any new ideas based around that approach if you feel there is a better way of doing it?